# Is there a pattern name for having complementing backer and isSet properties for each value type property in a class in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a class that implements interfaces w/ public value type properties. Upon initialization of the class all the value type properties get set to the value type's default value. But I need to know if that field has been actually set (specifically through model binding from my controller api).

To manage this I add 1 private backend property and 1 public isSet property per interface value type property and have the isSet property set when the value type property is actually populated after initialization.

For instance if the interface was like this

```
public interface IExampleInterface{
     int intValue {get; set;}
}

public class ExampleImplementor: IExampleInterface{
     public int intValue {get => _intValue; set{_intValue = value; intValueSet = true}}
     private int _intValue {get; set;}
     public int intValueSet {get;set;}
}
```

Is there a name for this pattern?

Comment: Why not use `int?`?

Comment: The problem of using `Nullable<T>` is that the semantics are wrong. `HasValue` has a specific meaning that's not the same as `IsSet`. But @shingo has a point. Consider creating a type like `ClearlySettable<T>` whose implementation looks like `Nullable<T>` (which is basically a `T` and a `HasValue` Boolean). If you set up conversion operators properly, you might end up with an elegant solution. No, I don't know a name for this pattern

Comment: @Flydog57 I agree that a wrapper with conversions might be more semantic, but I don't think it's clear that `Nullable<T>` is insufficient. It's not clear what it means for a feels kind of property, or variable to not have been set in C# because there's a default value for every type which is indeed assigned to it if another is not provided.

Comment: @shingo, you can't use type "int?" because you must implement an int not an "int?".

Comment: @Flydog57 as i'm forced to implement the interface, I don't think I'd be able to have a new type in place of the required contact properties. Ideally I'd love to have a single property instead of 3 (like int? which doesn't work) but right now I'm not able to find a way to do that as w/o a name, it's not an easy fix to search for.

Comment: I think that you are adding useless complexity in code...  If you want to know that a value has not been initialized explicitly, then use a nullable field for the backing store (and either throw or return a default from set... but if you return a default, then why not set it initially?). Or use some lazy loading if the reason to not initialize it is because it is an expansive object to create.

Comment: @Phil1970 I think you're right. I could just have a public backer nullable property and made that the field that is referenced when the decision needs to be made as to whether the value exists or not. I'm so used to the expectation that backend properties need to be private but that's not a requirement. TBH, i think I ultimately was more interested in whether there was a better way around this whole convoluted process. But I appreciate you pointing this out. If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't have a name for your pattern.  However, this is how I'd implement it:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public interface IExampleInterface
{
    int IntValue { get; set; }
}

internal class ExampleClass : IExampleInterface
{
    private int intValue = default;
    public bool IntValueHasBeenSet { get; private set; } = false;
    public int IntValue { 
        get => HandleGetter(intValue, IntValueHasBeenSet);
        set
        {
            intValue = value; 
            IntValueHasBeenSet = true;
        }
    }

    private T HandleGetter<T>(T value, bool hasBeenSet, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
    {
        if (!hasBeenSet)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Attempt to read value from property '{memberName}' before it has been set");
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Note that the backing field is a backing *field*, not a property like you show.  I also make the "Has been set" bit publicly read-only (you don't want your callers to change the value of that bit; it's only something your code should do).

Finally, I'm assuming that you want to throw an exception if someone tries to read the property before it's been set.  The way I have it setup, it will throw and exception with this error message:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Attempt to read value from property 'IntValue' before it has been set'

The `HandleGetter` method can be reused for properties of any type that you might have in your class.

If you come up with a name for your pattern, you might consider creating a `YourPatternNameException` to throw here.

FWIW, I also changed your code to more normal casing (Pascal case for types, methods and properties, and camel case for fields).